# Determine Lengths of Columns in Matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix, vhdl, counter

I am to determine the length of each column in a 4x4 matrix. The lengths of each columns are counted from the bottom of each column upwards and are only counted from the initial '1' accessed onwards.

```
1110   
0111
0110
0001
```

Column1=1, Column2=3, Column3=3, Column4=4 etc...

Does anyone have any ideas how I could do this? I have thus far attempted to produce a matrix alongside a function to extract each of the columns.

```
type col_mat is array (0 to 3) of std_logic;
type matrix is array (0 to 3, 0 to 3) of std_logic;

signal M: matrix;
signal temp_col : col_mat;
signal count    : unsigned (1 downto 0):= "00"; 

function extract_col(x: matrix; column : integer) return col_mat is
variable ret: col_mat;
begin 
    for i in col_mat'range loop 
        ret(i) := x(i,column)
    end loop;
    return ret; 

end function;

begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then 
         temp_col<= extract_col(M, to_integer(count) );
         count <= count+1;
    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: How can a row have a bottom and top? Do you mean a column? Your example text uses one-based indices, but the VHDL code uses zero-based indices. Please review your question.

Comment: I have edited it now. didn't mean to write row then

Comment: So, you want to find the highest set bit position in the column vector? A general method would be to: 1) invert the vector; 2) generate new vector and convert the binary number to twos complement; 3) logical AND of both vectors => gives a one hot encoded value where a 1 is at the position of the MSB. Then you can use a small LUT to get the result. Another option, since the Matrix is rather small, is to just feed each column vector to a LUT which decodes the value.

Comment: The function `extract_col` looks good. But, the given code example does not analyse. How about just another function which scans through a column? To give you a pointer: you can also exit a for loop before reaching the end.

Comment: I want to find the highest set bit position as I need to find the length of the columns. This bit of code is part of a much wider algorithm. The actual matrix will be much larger but this was just used as an example.

Comment: You're basically describing a priority encoder for a column. There'll be some limit as to how big (the number of column elements) a priority encoder can be based on the clock rate and the target device assuming it will be in that unlabeled process.  How big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing a priority encoder and from the looks of it you're implying it operates in one clock, which can run into some clock rate limit based on the target device (assuming you'll synthesize).

A priority encode can be an if statement, a case statement, a loop statement with an exit (as Martin Zabel commented), describe one combinatorially with logic operators or with a conditional signal assignment.

For this particular use a loop statement is the most compact and one has been added to your process.

The following code is derived from your question, fleshed out into [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The results are in terms of array type indexes (starting from 0).

I added a pipeline register for count named column as well as registers for a signal to specify a '1' was found (found_1) and the highest row value a '1' is found in (imaginatively named row):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity column is
end entity;

architecture foo of column is

    type col_mat is array (0 to 3) of std_logic;
    type matrix is array (0 to 3, 0 to 3) of std_logic;  -- (row,column)

    -- signal M: matrix;

    -- 1110
    -- 0111
    -- 0110
    -- 0001
    --
    -- Column1=1, Column2=3, Column3=3, Column4=4 etc...
    --
    -- column0 = 0, column1 =  2 column2 = 2, column3 = 3
    --  (matrix is defined so (0,0) is the upper left hand corner)
    --  Looking for the highest column index occupied by a '1'

    signal M:   matrix := (   -- for demo provide matrix default value
                    ('1','1','1','0'),   -- row 0
                    ('0','1','1','1'),
                    ('0','1','1','0'),
                    ('0','0','0','1')    -- row 3
                );

    -- signal temp_col:  col_mat;
    signal count:     unsigned (1 downto 0):= "00"; 

    function extract_col(x: matrix; column:  integer) return col_mat is
    variable ret: col_mat;
    begin 
        for i in col_mat'range loop 
            ret(i) := x(i,column);  -- was missing semicolon
        end loop;
        return ret; 
    end function;

    -- added signals:
    signal clk:     std_logic := '1';  -- rising_edge() requires 0 -> 1 trans
    signal found_1: std_logic := '0';
    signal column:  unsigned (1 downto 0);
    signal row:     integer range 0 to 3;
    signal mat_col: col_mat;
begin

UNLABELED:
    process (clk)
        variable temp_col: col_mat;   -- made temp_col a variable, use immediately
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then 
             temp_col := extract_col(M, to_integer(count));  -- was signal
             -- priority encoder:                             -- added loop

             for i in temp_col'RIGHT downto temp_col'LEFT loop -- highest first
                 if temp_col(i) = '1' then
                     found_1 <= '1';
                     column <= count;
                     row <= i;
                     exit;
                 else
                     found_1 <= '0';
                 end if;
             end loop;
             mat_col <= temp_col;  -- added
             count <= count + 1;
        end if;
    end process;

CLOCK:   -- Added clock process
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 90 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And when simulated this gives:

[image: column.png]

I added mat_col because the tool I used doesn't do delta cycle waveforms and variables have no notion of time. temp_col was made a variable to allow it's value to be used in immediately after it's assigned (an updated signal value is not available in the current simulation cycle).

You can also see I provided a default value for M from your question.